# Cannot set color for GMSPolyline with Google Map SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, colors, google-maps-sdk-ios, polyline

I'm using google map sdk in iOS 7.1

How can I set color for GMSPolyline, the default is black.
I have try with setStrokeColor and setSpans:

```
setStrokeColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xff0000, 1)
setSpans:@[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xff0000, 1)]]
```

but it no have effect, I can only change the opacity by set alpha.
Anyone can help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: need to see UIColorFromRGB

Comment: It's just a marco from [UIColor colorWith...]
I also try normal UIColor init :(

Comment: Not sure then. Is your macro expecting the second parameter? This works for me. GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to color polylines. [Google's iOS SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes#change_the_color_of_a_polyline) has good info on this.

The simplest way is to set the polyline's `strokeColor` property:

```
polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

For more complex stuff, you'll want: `GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:(UIColor *)color`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_style_span

They say to use `spans`, even to set the entire line's color:

```
polyline.spans = @[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:[UIColor redColor]]];
```

Alternating white/black every 500 "segments" (changes with zoom, maybe meters?):

```
NSArray *styles = @[[GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:[UIColor whiteColor]],
                    [GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];
NSArray *lengths = @[@(500), @(500)];

[polyline setSpans:GMSStyleSpans(polyline.path, styles, lengths, kGMSLengthRhumb)];
```

... useful for making your own train polylines, for example.

Comment: I don't know what my iphone wrong... but, my app draw color path on other iphone :( .. but on my iphone (iphone 4), it's only have gray color.

Comment: Try updating to the latest Maps SDK version, I recall there being a release note about a polyline color fix.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with 1.7 version. Update to 1.8 (current).