# Multiple colour in GMSPolyline

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I have drawn route between two places with 3 waypoints, I need to set green colour from starting place to first way point, then blue colour from first way point to second way point, likewise I need to set different colours based on waypoint. Any help.? TIA!!

For reference
[image: for referance]

Comment: i dont have any idea to set different colour.. but this code change colour based on given values in length. "let styles: [Any] = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.white), GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor.black)]
                let lengths: [Any] = [(500), (500)]
                polyLine.spans = GMSStyleSpans(rootLine.path!, styles as! [GMSStrokeStyle], lengths as! [NSNumber], kGMSLengthRhumb)"

Comment: referred from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24124614/7266861